# Find distribution of 4 points in a given shape, so that areas of Voronoi Diagram have the same and biggest size

Tags: python, shapes, area, points, voronoi

I have given a random shape, wherein I want to place 4 (or any other number) dots. The dots should be distributed, so that all areas of their Voronoi-Diagram have the same size of area and have the biggest size of area possible. I want to find an algorithm that I can implement in Python.
Any ideas how to start?

The algorithm should find the best distribution of a swarm of drones that is discovering a room.

Answer (score 1):

A natural approach is to pick some arbitrary starting points and apply the [Lloyd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm) repeatedly moving the sites to their Voronoi centers. It isn't guaranteed to get the optimal configuration but generally gives a much nice (and nearly locally optimal) configuration in a few steps.

In practice the ugliest part of the code is restricting the Voronoi cells to the polygonal domain. See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59754658/voronoi-regions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471445/how-to-find-intersection-points-of-overhanging-lines-of-voronoi-diagram-intersec) among other duplicates of this question.

Here is an alternative that maybe easier to implement quickly. [Rasterize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) your polygonal domain, computing finite set of points inside the polygon. Now run [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) which is just the discrete variant of Lloyd's method (and also [in scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html)) to find your locations. This way, you avoid the effort of trimming infinite Voronoi cells and only have to rely on a geometric inside-outside test for the input polygon to do your rasterization. The result has a clear accuracy-performance trade-off: the finer you discretize the domain, the longer it will take. But in practice, the vast majority of the benefit (getting a reasonably balanced partition) comes with a coarse approximation and just a few clustering iterations.

Finally, implementing things is a lot more complex if you need to use geodesic distances that don't allow sites to see directly around non-corners of the domain. (For example, see Figure 2a [here](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/drl/wiki/images/a/ac/NonConvexVoronoiCoverage_ICRA10.pdf).)