# Voronoi Regions

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, area, voronoi

I'm facing issues when trying to create voronoi regions in MATLAB and handle infinite vertices. I am relatively inexperienced in programming which I feel is hampering my ability to solve this problem.

I want to trace specific locations near the central nodes of the voronoi sub-polygons using the function `inpolygon`. I can not utilise the function if one of the vertices is Infinite (INF). Therefore, I wanted to create a grid around the voronoi split ([As seen in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6tMx.jpg)), and only consider the region within this grid, thereby neglecting the infinite vertices.

What I have done so far:

I already have a certain 100 pairs of Latitudes and Longitudes of nodes, around which I create a voronoi split using `voronoi(x_coordinates, y_coordinates)` function.

When I have to determine the various coordinates of the sub-polygons within this split, I use the
`[V,C] = voronoin([x_coordinates, y_coordinates]);`

Till now, this gives me all the of voronoi regions in `V` and all indexes of vertices for all sub-polygons (voronoi regions) in `C`.

Then I have implemented a function which uses inpolygon and takes x and y coordinates of the point that has to be traced within one of the voronoi regions. And here is where I am stuck. I am trying to implement a grid all around, but can not find the new intersecting vertices of the grid and the voronoi sub-region to find the new vertices of the voronoi sub-polygons.

Also, if there is any other way to achieve the same task, any help would be highly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I initially had simply negelected taking the inf vertice for the ```inpolygon``` usage, and the data that I am presently working on, works okay.

But if for eg. I decide to split the entire region is less number of zones (4 voronoi splits), I can not simply just neglect the **inf** vertice.

Comment: This seems to be the same issue as addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471445/how-to-find-internsection-points-of-overhanging-lines-of-voronoi-diagram-interse